# htaccess: request file by partial name

Tags: htaccess

With the assistance of htaccess, is it possible to have files stored as...

```
/content/001 Some sort of description.html
/content/002 Some sort of description.html
```

...or as...

```
/content/Some sort of description.001
/content/Some sort of description.002
```

...and get the desired file by requesting only the numeric portion of the name?

```
$.get("content/001", function(data) {
   • • • 
}, "html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the two examples you posted since there is no way to "search" for an arbitrary file based on a URL *pattern* AFAIK, without perhaps using a custom module.

However, if your files were named like the following instead, then it's possible to do this using MultiViews (mod_negotiation):

```
001.some-sort-of-description.html
002.another-description.html
```

Note the critical placement of the dots (`.`) to create file extension(s).

So, the number `001` is the file basename and `some-sort-of-description` and `html` are *file extensions*, then you can use MultiViews (mod_negotiation) to serve the appropriate file by requesting just the numeric portion of the filename.

It's important to end with a "known" file extension (like `.html`, `.php` or `.txt` etc.) that returns an appropriate mime-type. Simply naming the file `001.some-sort-of-description` does not appear to be sufficient.

For this to work, you need to enable the broadest scope of MultiViews matching: `Any`. This potentially has security implications so only enable it on the specific directory that contains only your *content* files.

For example, in the `/content/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +MultiViews
MultiviewsMatch Any
```

Requesting just `/content/001` or `/content/002` should then serve the corresponding file. If there are two files with the same "number" then the *smallest* file is returned.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#multiviewsmatch